# What is the exact probability distribution for a two group experiment?

Tags: probability, distributions, experiment-design

I recently conducted an experiment testing the effect of a new treatment (compared to a control). I want to compare the effect I observed to the probability distribution for all possible effects. But before I can do that, I need to calculate the probability distribution for this experiment. How do I do this?

In this experiment, 4 units were randomly assigned to the treatment group and the other 4 were assigned to the control. The dependent variable has two categories (success vs failure). After the exposure period, I calculated the difference between the two proportions.

Here's what I'm thinking the probability distribution for all possible differences would look like:

[image: Probability Distribution Difference in Proportions]

Is this right?

Comment: If $T \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4,.5)$ and, independently $C \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4,.5),$ and you want the distribution of $D = T - C,$ then your probabilities are correct to three places.